# two different activebackground color for a button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello so I'm learning tkinter in python 3.10.5
and so take a look at this and I'll explain

```
from tkinter import*
window=Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)
def txt():
    btn.config(text='test')
btn=Button(window,text='',activebackground=('crimson' if btn else 'lime'),command=txt)
btn.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)

window.mainloop()
```

so I have a button that takes the whole window and I want to write in activebackground part that if the button has no text in it activebackground color would be crimson otherwise lime. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `activebackground` within `btn.config` method and use `if ... else` to toggle. E.g.:

```
from tkinter import*
window=Tk()
window.geometry('400x400')
window.resizable(width=False,height=False)

def txt():
    if btn['text'] == '':
        btn.config(text='test', activebackground='lime')
    else:
        btn.config(text='', activebackground='crimson')
    
btn=Button(window,text='',activebackground='crimson', command=txt)
btn.pack(expand=True,fill=BOTH)

window.mainloop()
```